# WebRTC iOS local video track bytesSent is 0

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have created my iOS WebRTC app using GoogleWebRTC version 1.1.22075 in Cocoapods. The other client is a web app. We have established the connection between the two WebRTC client. The audio is fine. Both WebRTC client can receive and send audio but when it comes to video the iOS local video track has no bytes sent at all. In the RTCLegacyStatsReport of iOS app the bytesSent for for video is 0.

Below is that stats for video:

`reportId: ssrc_2385920718_send
type: ssrc
googAdaptationChanges: 0
ssrc: 2385920718
googFrameWidthSent: 0
googBandwidthLimitedResolution: false
bytesSent: 0
googCodecName: VP8
codecImplementationName: unknown
googFirsReceived: 0
packetsLost: 0
googHasEnteredLowResolution: false
googCpuLimitedResolution: false
googTrackId: ios_local_video_stream
framesEncoded: 0
googPlisReceived: 0
mediaType: video
packetsSent: 0
googFrameRateSent: 0
googContentType: realtime
googFrameHeightSent: 0
googNacksReceived: 0
googFrameRateInput: 0
transportId: Channel-audio-1
googAvgEncodeMs: 0
googRtt: 0
googEncodeUsagePercent: 0`

And here's the code of how I get the capture device, creation of local video track, and rendering video to view locally.

```
func onLocalStreamReadyForRender() {
    print("onLocalStreamReadyForRender")
    let frame = localVideoView!.frame

    let rtcVideoView = RTCCameraPreviewView.init(frame: CGRect.init())
    rtcVideoView.frame = frame
    rtcVideoView.frame.origin.x = 0
    rtcVideoView.frame.origin.y = 0
    self.localVideoView?.addSubview(rtcVideoView)

    currVideoCaptureSession!.startRunning()

    if let _ = currVideoCaptureSession {
        rtcVideoView.captureSession = currVideoCaptureSession!
    }
}

fileprivate func onVideoTrackCreated(_ videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?, _ videoSource: RTCVideoSource?, _ videoCaptureSession: AVCaptureSession?) {
    print("onVideoTrackCreated")

    currVideoTrack = videoTrack
    currVideoSource = videoSource
    currVideoCaptureSession = videoCaptureSession

    if let _ = currVideoTrack {
        localStream!.addVideoTrack(videoTrack!)
        print("localstream added video track with track id \(String(describing: currVideoTrack?.trackId))")

        onLocalStreamReadyForRender()
    }

    for stream in peerConn!.localStreams {
        if stream.streamId == Config.mediaTrackLabel {
            peerConn!.remove(localStream!)
        }
    }

    peerConn!.add(localStream!)
}

func createLocalVideoTrack(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) {
    if let captureDevice = getCaptureDevice(position: position) {
        print("createLocalVideoTrack")

        let videoSource = peerConnFactory.videoSource()
        let rtcCamVidCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)

        rtcCamVidCapturer.startCapture(
            with: captureDevice.device,
            format: captureDevice.format,
            fps: captureDevice.fps,
            completionHandler:
            {
                (error: Error?) in
                if let captureError = error {
                    print("Error RTCCameraVideoCapturer startCapture \(captureError)")
                }
                else {
                    print("RTCCameraVideoCapturer startCapture success")
                    let videoTrack = self.peerConnFactory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: Config.mediaTrackVideoLabel)
                    self.mediaTrackDelegate?.onVideoTrackCreated(videoTrack, videoSource, rtcCamVidCapturer.captureSession)
                }
            })
    }
}

func getCaptureDevice(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> (device: AVCaptureDevice, format: AVCaptureDevice.Format, fps: Int)? {
    for avCaptureDevice in RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices() {
        if avCaptureDevice.position == position {
            let supportedActiveFormat = avCaptureDevice.activeFormat
            let maxFrameRate = supportedActiveFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges[0].maxFrameRate
            let minFrameRate = supportedActiveFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges[0].minFrameRate
            //let midFrameRate = minFrameRate + ((maxFrameRate - minFrameRate)/2)
            let fps = maxFrameRate

            print("getCaptureDevice uniqueId:\(avCaptureDevice.uniqueID), supportedActiveFormat:\(supportedActiveFormat), fps:\(fps), deviceType:\(avCaptureDevice.deviceType), isConnected:\(avCaptureDevice.isConnected), localizedName:\(avCaptureDevice.localizedName)")

            return (device: avCaptureDevice, format: supportedActiveFormat, fps: Int(fps))
        }
    }

    print("Error no capture device returned")
    return nil
}
```

by the way Im testing it on iPad mini 2nd gen OS version 11.2.6

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looking through the rtc stats, it has the line "codecImplementationName: unknown". Did I miss something out initializing my RTCPeerConnectionFactory?

`let decoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory.init()
let encoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory.init()

let videoCodedInfo = RTCVideoCodecInfo.init(name: "VP8")
encoderFactory.preferredCodec = videoCodedInfo

peerConnFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init(encoderFactory: encoderFactory, decoderFactory: decoderFactory)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved the issue. It was caused by RTCCameraVideoCapturer being destroyed as soon as it was created.